# How can call two API with condition in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, react-redux

I'm in the learning phase so please let me know if something feels illogical. I have been trying to use show result in a way that by default a user should see the trending API results and when he starts searching the other API with search query will trigger or get called. I tried to use if-else but there is no result. It shows the blank. I do not know how can I achieve it. Would really appreciate it if you can help me with this.

when I get the data I am displaying that data in the card below as you will see using the map function, and if the search is blank am trying to show the error. but I am getting a blank card as you can see in the image. how can I also fix this?

[image]

Please see the code I have tried. I do not know if it is the logical way or not. Thanks a million in advance.

```
import React ,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Grid, Button, Card, CardActionArea, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Watchlist from '../Products/Watchlist.jsx';
import Error from '../Error/Error.jsx';


const useStyles = makeStyles (theme => ({
    cardButton:{
        '&:hover':{
           backgroundColor:'#356E44',
           color: 'white',
        }
    },
Main:{
    width: "100vw",
    justifyContent: " flex-start",
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    alignItems: "stretch", 
    alignContent: " flex-start",
    columnGap: "20px",
    rowGap:"5px",
},
cardMain:{
    width: 'min-content',
    height: 'min-content',
    margin: '10px',
    '&:hover':{
        boxShadow: '5px 3px 5px white',
     }
},

cardImage:{
    height: '150px',
    marginLeft: '7px',
    marginRight: '7px',
    marginTop: '5px',
    objectFit: 'cover',
},
cardContent: {
    width: '250px',
    height: '50px',
    wordBreak: 'break-word',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    fontWeight: 'bolder',
},
typography1:{
    float: 'right',
   
},
typography2:{
    float: 'left',
},
}));


const Produts = (props) =>{
    

const classes = useStyles();

const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);
 
 const [watchlist, setWatchlist] = useState ([]);

 const filterData = ((val) => {

     const keyword = props.searchText;

     if (keyword !== "") {
         return val
     } 
     else if (val.original_title?.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchText?.toLowerCase())) {
         return val
     } 
     
  } );


   




useEffect (()=> {
    const getMovieList  = async () => {
        const TrendingUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=API_keyID' ;
        
        const allResultsUrl = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=API_keyID&query=${props.searchText}`;
             
        const response = await fetch (props.searchText ? TrendingUrl : allResultsUrl);
                try {
                    const responseJson = await response.json();
                    const data = (responseJson.results);
                    setMovieData(data);
                    console.log(data)
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
        
    };
 getMovieList();

 

 }, [props.searchText]);


 const handleWatchlist = (movieData) => {
     const newWatchlist = [...watchlist , movieData];
     setWatchlist (newWatchlist);
    }

return (
    <> 
        <Grid
        item
        xs
        container
        direction="column"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-start"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "black", width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
        >
            <div  className ={classes.Main} > { movieData.length === 0 ? (<h1 style = {{color: 'red', fontSize : "2rem"}}>No search results found</h1>)
                : movieData.filter(filterData).map((movie) =>{
                return(
                    <Card className={classes.cardMain}  key={movie.id}>
                <CardActionArea>
                    <CardMedia className = {classes.cardImage}>
                        <img style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}} 
                            src ={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}`} 
                            alt = "movie poster"/>
                    </CardMedia>
                    <CardContent className = {classes.cardContent}>
                        <Typography>  {movie.original_title} </Typography>
                        <Typography 
                                    className = {classes.typography1} 
                                    variant="body2" 
                                    component = "p"
                            > {movie.release_date} 
                            </Typography>
                        <Rating 
                                className = {classes.typography2} 
                                name = "ratings"
                                value =  {movie.vote_average/2} 
                                precision={0.5}
                                readOnly                                
                        />  
                        
                    </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
                <CardActions style = {{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}} >
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small">Watch</Button>
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton} size = "small" >Share</Button>
                    <Button className = {classes.cardButton}size = "small" onClick = { () => handleWatchlist(movie) }> Add </Button> 
                </CardActions>
               
            </Card>
                );
                
            })}
        
            </div>
        </Grid>
          
    </>
)
};

export default Produts;
```

Comment: You can't immediately log data after setting state. You need to use [`useEffect(() => console.log(movieData), [movieData]);`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to log the changed state instead.

Comment: He's logging `data`, not `movieData`, so that's not the issue I think. `data` will already contain the value that `movieData` will hold on the next render.

Comment: Hey dude, don't replace your original questions with a completely irrelevant one. You just make it super confusing for other users to view this in the future. Just creat a new question if you have more to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. The code above is the correct answer to call api using conditioanl operator. However, why I could not see the result was because my useState hook was not having an initial value of empty string hence it was showing undefined: Code before:

```
  const[searchText, setSearchText] = useState();
```

Which after some reading and looking all line by line I found

it should be as below which is a proper empty string.

```
 const[searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
```

Answer (score 2):

I will split the API into two. Also, renamed the variables a bit for a better naming convention.

```
const fetchTrending = () => {
  const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=api_keyID';
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(trendingMovies => setMovies(trendingMovies))
    .catch(error => {
      // TODO: Do your error handling here
      console.error(error);
    });
};

const fetchQuery = search => {
  const url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api_keyID&query=${search}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(queriedMovies => setMovies(queriedMovies))
    .catch(error => {
      // TODO: Do your error handling here
      console.error(error);
    });
};

/* When the component is mounted, load trending movies
   This will only run once.
*/
useEffect(() => fetchTrending(), []);

// pass this handler to the onChange listener of your search field
const handleSearchChange = search => fetchQuery(search);
```

Comment: Hi I tried the way have described it above, but it is showing me the error saying Products.jsx:160 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: movieData.filter is not a function

Comment: Since you are not posting the full code, there is no way I can provide much help with that.

One possibility is `movieData` might become `null` or `undefined` at some point. Maybe it is the initial value of `useState` or returned by the APIs. Have you double checked it?

Comment: Hi sorry for the inconvenience I have updated my code. Please have a look @mathew . Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. I'm using [this little hook](https://gist.github.com/mariusbrataas/ffca05c210ec540b4fb9f4324c4f2e68) a lot for stuff like this.

It works the same as useMemo, but allows you to pass a callback that return a promise rather than immediately returning a value.

Use it like this:

```
import { usePromiseMemo } from 'usePromiseMemo';

function MyComponent() {
  const movieData = usePromiseMemo(
    () =>
      fetch(
        props.searchText
          ? `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api_keyID&query=${props.searchText}`
          : `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=api_keyID`
      )
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
          console.log('Raw data: ', r);
          const data = r.results;
          console.log('Data: ', data);
          return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }),
    [props.searchText]
  );

  return <></>;
}
```

**Also, what do you get from the "Raw data"-log?**

Comment: Hi I have update the full code hope this might help you more, and when I get the data I am displaying that data in the card below as you will see using map function, and if the search is blank am trying to show the error. Thanks a million again for help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `src` in the image is correct? It seems like a weird pattern.

Should it be  `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.poster_path}` rather than `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${movie.poster_path}`? **Mark the "/" between `original` and `${movie.poster_path}`**

Edit: [As seen in the docs](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images).

Comment: yeah, it does work fine I can see the data when I start to type with images and all no issues with image rendering, As I was following one video on youtube and it had the same pattern too. The only issue is of not getting the data if input am trying to call two api using if else in useeffect with await fetch function as you can see. Inshort i want to show trending api when no input and if input show search result